# Find if list contains any item contained in comma separated string

Tags: linq

I had created one list containing Food Category, Sub-Category, Code, FoodName( eg 11,12,2345,'Oats'). Now in my Hidden Field, there are multiple codes eg. 1123,2345,5678. Now what I am trying to get is Count of codes existing in list.
For Eg. in above context let's say if only 2345 exists in list which matches, then output should be 1.
If 1123,2345 exists in list which matches, then output should be 2. I had tried like below but not getting req. output.

```
public void GetCSWSTUCPAFreeRestrictBlkFood(string categoryId, string subCategoryId)
        {
            string rtnMsg = string.Empty;
            int itmAlreadyExistsCnt = 0;
            List<CurrentDietSummary> restrData = null;
             restrData = GetPARestrictedFood();
             var listCS = hfCheckedChildCS.Value.Split(',').ToList();

                if (restrData != null && restrData.Count > 0)
                    itmAlreadyExistsCnt = restrData.Count(x => x.CategoryId == Convert.ToInt32(categoryId) 
                            && x.SubCategoryId == Convert.ToInt32(subCategoryId)
                            && x.FoodCode.ToString() == listCS.Any().ToString());
                if (itmAlreadyExistsCnt == 1)
                    rtnMsg = "Detail corresponding to Item already exist.";
                else  (itmAlreadyExistsCnt > 1)  //Multiple items exists 
                    rtnMsg = "Detail corresponding to some Item(s) already exist.";
}
```

Tried to get req. output

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution. Done it like below:

```
public void GetCSWSTUCPAFreeRestrictBlkFood(int FreeRestrictBlk, bool isCateg, string categoryId, string subCategoryId)
        {
            string rtnMsg = string.Empty;
            int itmAlreadyExistsCnt = 0;
            List<CurrentDietSummary> restrData = null;
             restrData = GetPARestrictedFood();

                var listCS = hfCheckedChildCS.Value.Split(',').ToList();
                if (restrData != null && restrData.Count > 0)
                    itmAlreadyExistsCnt = restrData.Count(x => x.CategoryId == Convert.ToInt32(categoryId)
                            && x.SubCategoryId == Convert.ToInt32(subCategoryId)
                            && listCS.Contains(x.FoodCode.ToString()));
                if (itmAlreadyExistsCnt == 1)
                    rtnMsg = "Detail corresponding to Item already exist.";
                else  (itmAlreadyExistsCnt > 1)  //Multiple items exists 
                    rtnMsg = "Detail corresponding to some Item(s) already exist.";
}
```

Comment: ` = null`: don't do this, especially when you are immediately overwriting with the value you want.

Comment: So if a `FoodCode` happens to be the same as a `CategoryId` or `SubCategoryId` it is okay if it gets counted? You really shouldn't use `Contains` when dealing with multiple types of data.